# full screen login

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a login screen, and I need to get it working full screen.

I'm trying to place forms on top of the username and pas only I'm not getting the position right

here is an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TSbRY/

```
   #loginbackground{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        background: url(http://ivojonkers.com/loginscreentemp.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; 
}

    #loginbackground form{
        width:18.667%;
        height:7.466%;
        position:absolute;
        top:51.4%;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-8.867%;
 }

    #loginbackground input{
        width:100%;
        height:31.25%;
        background-color:#F00;
        border:none;
        font:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size:18px;
        position: absolute;
 }
```

​

My problem is that I want to place the forms on the username and pas and be there at every screen resolution, so when you're scaling your browser you need to get the forms on top of the part where you think can type in the img.

ash you can see in the full screen overhere http://fiddle.jshell.net/TSbRY/show/ it will fit on some screen resolutions but not on all

Comment: Need more info, too vauge

Comment: This is just much too vague to answer.

Comment: i need to place the forms on top of the place it needs to be in the img and it needs to be there on every screen resolution, don't know how to explain this better

Comment: Use HTML and CSS to design the login page, instead of using images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is a way you can solve this easily. Either you do what [Bastian Rang said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096103) or you can go ahead and break up that image into two pictures. So, the login information will be a separate image. In that way, you can center, and resize that through CSS or JavaScript. And set that login panel to position relative and you can easily place inputs inside and move it around easily. I can explain more if necessary. The problem you are facing occurs because the image you have combines the input region and the background. Split them up and it will be so much easier.

[**[Updated] Design of OP's login.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSbRY/24/)

**You need to see it in Google Chrome and use the latest version of it. Only tested on Google Chrome.**

```
<div style = "height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;
position:fixed;">
<div style = "background:red;height:55%;top:0;left:0;right:0;position:absolute;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3BBCFE, #64D5FF,#06ADFE);"></div>
<div style = "background:blue;height:45%;top:55%;left:0;right:0;position:absolute;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59D2FF,#41C1FE);"></div>
<div style = "background:green;height:20%;width:40%;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #01C5FF,#076799);border-radius:4px;
              box-shadow:0 0 120px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);position:absolute;left:30%;right:0;top:40%;
              border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border-top:none;border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
                  <input type = "text" style = "position:absolute;left:5%;top:18%;right:5%;width:90%;height:25%;border:none;background:#00A2ED;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5),inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:4px;"/>
                  <input type = "text" style = "position:absolute;left:5%;top:53%;right:5%;height:25%;width:90%;border:none;background:#00A2ED;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5),inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:4px;"/>
</div>
```

You can see how I used position: absolute and position: relative with % for height, width, top, bottom, left, and right to create the effect.

Please don't just copy it. Try to understand how this works, it will serve you better in the long run.

I am not sure if you are expecting us to make the images for you and provide the code for you. But if you are, I would like to say that the community will not write the code for you but will guide you in the right path.

What you need to do know is choose the smarter path. A statement such as "I need to support all browsers" is rather immature. Start by choosing your audience by studying the modern browser trends and which browsers are used the most. Start by choosing the best browsers to start developing for. There are over 160 browsers out there and it is challenging or nearly impossible to develop complicated detailed layouts like yours (i.e. box-shadows).

There are basically two options:

- pure CSS*
- using images and CSS

Pure CSS can be adjusted easily while images become quite static and take time to create (if you are not well versed with graphics) and/or edit. Images will have to be made in something like Photoshop, Fireworks, GIMP, or Pixlr.com to create the images and then scale them as necessary by the browser (using CSS).

Again this is not perfect for all browsers. And I will close by saying that the community will not make the images for you - that will be your job.

Disclaimer: Simple HTML will be rendered quite equally across different browsers, but more complex ones involving box-shadows and gradients will not.

I have made a small diagram representing the cutouts which can be done to achieve the perfection and cross-browser compatibility you are looking for. But this is quite challenging. **Download to the image to see the notes/markings in full resolution.**

Look into *9-patch* images: basically, use that concept when you decide to break these images up.

[image: Download to see the notes]

Comment: +1. @IvoJonkers, this is a good starting point to draw it without an Image. You can set width and height in pixels too to have the box always of the same size. Use Gradient generator to achieve the colors you need for background, and apply your background-color and input fields borders to your login form.

Comment: now the only problem is how to get this working in other browsers?

Comment: @IvoJonkers: That is a problem all developers face...perfect solution does not really exist. but try converting them to images if you want to avoid using gradients. And try this http://prefixr.com/

Comment: so that's way i like to use a img only the positioning is way harder then

Comment: don't use AN image, use multiple images

Comment: so this still is not solving my problem but i now know how to start i will split the img and position them separably

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Your stated "My problem is that I want to place the forms on the username and pas and be there at every screen resolution, so when you're scaling your browser you need to get the forms on top of the part where you think can type in the img." is solved with this method.

Comment: i agree now only its just working in chrome and i need to support all browsers

Comment: i have updated my original post with regards to your comment.

Comment: I'm really not asking you but i was looking for a way to make a full screen login of my images that's supported in IE9 , chrome and firefox i noticed that working with gradients is not the best solution so i will change the images so i can just make a background and a floating div to align in the center

Comment: @IvoJonkers: This update should provide the support you need for the webpage. But it is quite tedious.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

That is an image.

With a pixel width / height, you will have a fixed image, and then no full screen;

With a percent width / height, you will have image stretching / rescaling, and you will have no clue on where or how to reposition your form fields.

What you CAN do is to

1) render the image with CSS only, because it is a simple image, and you can achieve that with CSS3 `Gradients`, `Border-radius` and `Box-shadow` properties;

or

2) use a fixed image, set `margin: 0 auto` to set it always at center. Then, put a background-color around to fill the rest of the screen.

or

3) Split the image in two images: you resize the background image (the gradients), while you set fixed widths / heights only for the login box, leaving it always centered.

Comment: I am up-voting this because it is closest to the proper way to approach this. Unless there is a specific reason you have such a large (1500x1500) background image, other than you not knowing how to accomplish the same thing in pure CSS, then it's overkill. I would try and take a step back and reproach this in a more efficient way.

Comment: @AndreasLigios: There is a way you can achieve this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer when it was a lot lighter ;) Btw i don't understand the preserve edges etc... are they all different images ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Yes they are...like 9-patch files in android. but we can emulate that in html by cuttng images.

Answer (score 0):

i have no final solution, but some hints you can use:

1. You're mixing pixel and percent. that's never a good idea.
2. why do you use images as background? the image in your example is possible just with css using background gradients -> http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: i agree with the first one only its the height and width positioning not the height end width of the form so not a big problem write now i will fix that part later, when i'm using a css3 gradient its still the same problem with positioning

Comment: no, its not the same. images are fixed in pixels - if you change to percentages at all, you can use them with css

Comment: i still think it will not make any difference in the poisoning

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest a way, there can be many.

First use the  background image as actual image, img tag. Then place the input elements absolutely upon it using **z-index**. Calculate the height of image using the jquery .height(). And then dynamically decide the positioning of your input fields.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$width=$('img#backimage').width();
$height=$('img#backimage').height();

/*Code to decide the position of box based on image dimensions*/
$('form').css('top','your calculated value');

})
```

Other way would be to split your image into two parts. Use the background image for page and form separately. So use the form background image 'the blue box' separately and use pixel dimensions as width:400 px and adjust it to center. This lets you decide exactly where to position your element.

```
form{
background:url('yourbox.png');
width:400px; /*consider this is width of your backg image too*/ 
left:50%;
top:500px;
margin-left:-200px; /*To adjust to center*/
padding-top:20px; /*Adjust according to back image*/
padding-left:10 px;/*Adjust according to back image*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an image and using it you can't make it the way you want it to work. The better option is to use HTML markup to create the effect you want to. I created a similar page, here's the demo 
http://jsbin.com/alivas/1/

To check the code I used, see this link 
http://jsbin.com/alivas/1/edit

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried changing the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)?

Try changing the z-index of the forms to a positive number:

```
z-index:1;
```

If you want to see z-index in action: [Go Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_z-index)

Comment: its not the z-index its the place of the forms they need to be in the place of the username and pas

Comment: Well you really didn't explain. You just said: "Hey, fix this please!" You didn't give enough info, and that left room for assumptions.